# How does Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines (MARS) consider the minimum number of observations between knots in the forward pass?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, splines, piecewise-linear, mars

I try to explain my question with a simple example.

Let's say we have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. At the first two stages of the forward pass, effects of $x_1$ with a knot at $a_1$ and $x_2$ with a knot at $b_1$ are added so we have:
$$\beta_1max(0,a_1-x_1)+\beta_2max(0,x_1-a_1)+\beta_3max(0,b_1-x_2)+\beta_4max(0,x_2-b_1)$$
at the next step, let's assume that the best terms to be added to the mentioned model is from variable $x_2$ with another knot at $b_2$ where $b_2>b_1$. Now for example, let's consider two of the scenarios that this new term can be added:

1. $\beta_5max(0,x_2-b_2)$
2. $\beta_5max(0,x_1-a_1)max(0,b_2-x_2)+\beta_6max(0,x_1-a_1)max(0,x_2-b_2)$

Under the first scenario, $\beta_5max(0,x_2-b_2)$ is added along with $\beta_3max(0,b_1-x_2)+\beta_4max(0,x_2-b_1)$ which basically means forming the effect of $x_2$ with two knots at $b_1$ and $b_2$. Here, checking if there are enough observations between $b_1$ and $b_2$ to approve or reject $b_2$ as a new knot for $x_2$ is understandable. However in the second scenario, the hinge functions of $x_2$ at $b_2$ are added as interactions with $max(0,x_1-a_1)$.

Now the main question is:

Does MARS reject the candidate terms in second scenario (interaction scenario) if there aren't enough observations between $b_1$ and $b_2$? If yes, what's the reason for it?